# Efficient way to send a tensor of data through a function without a loop

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a neural network (my function):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

softplus = torch.nn.Softplus()

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = softplus(self.fc3(x))
        return x

net = Model()
```

I also have data in the form of a large tensor (note that here is a small example) that is generated on the fly (that is, each epoch I get a new tensor):

```
for epoch in range(10):
    data = torch.rand(5,3)
```

These data need to be sent to the network. The difficulty is that my function needs to take 4 values as an input, where 3 of them are each of the tensor in the data tensor (5x3 for 5 triples in this example), and the fourth input is the sum of the previous function outputs. The first triple is combined with an initial value of 0:

```
init_value = torch.tensor([0])
torch.cat((data[0],init_value))
```

So for my first input I concat the `init_value` to it and send it to the function. If this outputs from the network the value `1.2`, I need to send the next triple to the network as `[x,y,z,0+1.2]`. Where `x,y,z` is the second triple from the data tensor. From [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24417/does-torch-cat-work-with-backpropagation) it seems like `torch.cat` works with the `backward` operation which is needed and why I'm using it.

Is there an efficient way to do this? Currently what I'm doing is using a for loop, sending each tensor in the data tensor to the network and concatenating the sum of the values so far. But since this is a very large tensor it's not very optimal.

Answer (score 0):

It is a really strange requirement, have you ever tried to change your forward code in this model by simulating the process that your reuse previous outputs?
Normally we feed the network with inputs with shape [B,...] where B indicates the batch size, and the network calculates a batch simultaneously, and here in your example, it seems 5 is not the batch size, it more looks like the time axis in a sequential data, I really don't know whether you neglect the batch size dimension to simplify this problem.

Comment: Hmm interesting idea about the forward method. Though I'm not sure how to make it reuse the previous outputs without the same for loop issue. Regarding the batch size, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Isn't the batch here is 5? I'm sending 5 data points (each is tensor with a length of 4)

Comment: @Penguin My understanding is that you firstly use the first of five triplets to generate output 1, and then feed the second of five triplets and the ouput 1 to generate output 2, and then use the ouput 2 and the third triplet to generate output 3. So if the training procedure is just like I said, I don't regard 5 as the batch size, I will consider it  as the time dimension and all these 5 triplets are only one shot of a batch.

Comment: Not quite. I feed the first triple as an input rather than all 5. Each triple is an input (though it's missing the fourth value)